# Get external plug-in to fire in view

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple view model whereby I fill a div with content when a function is fired:

This is the function:

```
function loadPage(elem){

  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
      content.innerHTML = this.response;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', 'views/' + elem + '.html', true);
  xhr.send();

}
```

**The problem**

The problem is that when I load a plug-in - in this case `swiper` - it simply doesn't fire.

This is example swiper code which works perfectly when added to a page loaded "normally", but when added using the view method above, does not fire/load

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="assets/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        loop: true
    });
</script>
```

**The question**

How can I fire the plug-in when the view is loaded? No jQuery used.

Is there a better way to architect this?